# HOW to add a live template in Pycharm like '$var$.print'

Tags: python, pycharm, live-templates

I hope to create a template `type` so that when I typo `var.type`, I'll get the output like `type(var)`, but i couldnt find the similar template in settings of Pycharm, hope for some help!!!

Answer (score 1):

That's a postfix template, and [they still don't support custom postfix templates for Python](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30217).

From the [help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html#postfix_completion):

> You can edit the predefined postfix templates, for example, to replace a long key with a shorter one, or to expand the list of applicable expression types. Due to PyCharm limitations, you cannot create any custom postfix templates for Python.

Comment: Pycharm need to provide this function

Comment: @andydy There's a [request on their issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30217), go vote for that.